# Verlinde formula of correlation functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, correlation-functions

The well-known Verlinde formula states that under $S$-transformation, the characters of a (rational) chiral algebra transform into each other,
$$
\chi_i (- 1/\tau) = \sum S_{ij} \chi_j(\tau) \ ,
$$
where $\chi_i$ is the character of the representation associated with a primary $\phi_i$.

I wonder how to generalize this transformation to the torus one/n-point point functions, like
$$
\langle a\rangle_i \equiv  \operatorname{tr}_{\phi_i} a(z) q^{L_0 - c/24} b^h ,
$$
where $h$ denotes additional symmetries. Do we need to know how $a(z)$ transforms under $S$?